# Sum up two steps into one step

Tags: c#

In a class in a console application I wrote a method that reads many integer inputs and sums them up. The inputs calls for another method written in another class (`Input.ReadIntegerConsole()`) that's supposed to read the input, and then make the operations of the first class continue if the input is an integer, or otherwise to write "invalid choice", this way:

```
private void ReadInputAndSumNumbers()
{
    Console.Write("\nNumber you choose? ");
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberChosen);
    numberChosen = Input.ReadIntegerConsole();
    sum += numberChosen;
```

etc. The problem is that this way, when I run the application, the console asks: Number you choose? then whatever I input, the program does nothing. At this point I will put another input and only now the `ReadIntegerConsole` method starts: if it is an integer the operations continue, otherwise the program displays "invalid choice". How to do it so the program does everything in one step instead of two steps, so it reads my input and immediately verifies if it is an integer or not and decides to continue or to display "invalid choice"? How to do it without having to write two inputs? I know for sure that the Input.ReadIntegerConsole code is written correctly and that's why I didn't display it here. I tried writing in many different parts of the class that `numberChosen = Input.ReadIntegerConsole()` but it has never worked. I tried also writing `numberChosen=int.Parse(ConsoleReadLine())=Input.ReadIntegerConsole()` but of course it doesn't work.

Comment: What does the method **ReadIntergerConsole** have in it? it looks like you're doing nothing with your first console.readline\

Comment: More detail about your code will help understand the problem better. Can you please add the code for your other method? Meanwhile, try removing this line `int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberChosen)` once.

Comment: It is impossible to understand what's going wrong without more code. Please add the code that calls this snippet and also the code of ReadIntegerConsole

Comment: Wow thank you SO MUCH everyone! You were right Arghya C, removing that line did the trick, now it works! Like you said, code, the first console.readline is useless. I thought that without it, though, the program wouldn't have been able to read my input, so the whole thing wouldn't have worked. But it looks like that the program CAN read my input without the Console.ReadLine. Thank you SO MUCH! I had spent a couple hours trying to figure it out. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Console.Write("\nNumber you choose? ");
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberChosen);
numberChosen = Input.ReadIntegerConsole();
sum += numberChosen;
```

You didn't provide the implementation of `Input.ReadIntegerConsole` but its a fair guess that it *also* calls `Console.ReadLine` and parses it into an int (same as the line above it). So basically, your code is doing:

1. Print a message
2. Wait for user input, parse into an `int` and store in `numberChosen`
3. Call `Input.ReadIntegerConsole` which likely waits for user input, parses it into an `int` and returns it, and store it in `numberChosen`
4. Add the number to `sum`

So when you input the first number, it does exactly what you think, but `Input.ReadIntegerConsole` asks for *another* input and overwrites the original one (hence if you enter junk, it says "invalid value"). This second read from the console explains why the program appears to do nothing, since its waiting for more input.

Removing the manual `Console.ReadLine` gets rid of the redundant read/parse, which is why it fixed your code. Its not that it works without `Console.ReadLine`, its that the method you are using hides a call to it.

Comment: Yes it is exactly like that!!! The Input.ReadIntegerConsole DOES call for another Console.ReadLine!  Now I see why the program waited for another input. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking what I think you're asking, I think you want this:

```
private void ReadInputAndSumNumbers()
{
    Console.Write("\nNumber you choose? ");
    int numberChosen;
    if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberChosen)) {
        sum += numberChosen;
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice.");
    }
}
```

`int.TryParse` is a method with an `out` parameter, which means the result of parsing will be assigned to numberChosen. It returns a `bool`, however: true if successful (string passed is parseable into an `int`), or false if unsuccessful. So what it's saying is:

If int.TryParse can create an int from the input string, the variable numberChosen has the result stored when the method finishes; add numberChosen to sum.
else, it was unsuccessful, and write "Invalid choice".

Out parameters can get a little confusing, but they're powerful. But if I did a poor job explaining, here are some links: [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), [out (C# reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx)

Comment: Side note: If you want to do this multiple times, you may want to put the method block in a loop until the user types a specific input, such as "DONE".